# How to Map Procedural Bricks on a Pyramid

Tags: texturing

I've created this pyramid from a default cube by deleting the top face and then merging the vertices at center. How do I get the bricks node to be horizontal on all faces?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is rather easy to do :).
Just unwrap your object using *Cube Projection* and connect your *UV map*.

1. Select all vertices of your object.
   Go to *UV > Cube Projection*

[image]

2. Connect nodes like in this image.
   Use the *UV output* - this will connect your *UV map* (that you just made).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add a Texture/Mapping (use Ctrl-T in Node Wrangler) and set the Texture coordinate to Camera.
[image]

Comment: Ok playing with that some more, I see that it depends on the camera location.  Is that going to work for you?

Comment: texture coordinates should not be a guess game. Learn how to use them.
Watch Bartek Skorupa’s video on how to [Manipulate texture coordinates](https://youtu.be/kAUmLcXhUj0?t=264) and https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/texture_coordinate.html